# Objective-C, accessing object variables within an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, object, nsarray

Is it possible to directly access an object variable with an array of objects like so..

```
NSArray *myObjectsInArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id) myClass,myOtherClass, nil];

NSLog(@"%d",[myObjectsInArray[0] returnSize]);   //works perfect

NSLog(@"%d",[myObjectsInArray[0].size]);  // error
```

I'm not sure if it's a syntax problem or if it cannot be accessed without a method. 
thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing an array like so `myArray[0]` is equivelant to calling `[myArray objectAtIndex:0]`. The return value of `objectAtIndex:` is `id`. Any method call may be sent to an `id` reference. However, the compiler will not allow the use of the dot syntax shortcut to call methods on it.

If you really want to use the dot syntax, you need to cast it.

```
NSLog(@"%d",[((MyClass*)myObjectsInArray[0]).size]);
```